# Different outputs from same model lmer modelsummary sjPlot

Tags: r, lme4, summary, sjplot, modelsummary

I am running into a small issue that i can't figure my head around.

I developed a model that I test using `lmer`. Full code:

```
#importing library
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)
library(car)
library(easystats)
library(modelsummary)
library(lme4)

df <- Mod_Final_R1R2_Meta_moderation_sharing
summary(df)

df_x <- subset(df, Category == "x")

modelZ <- lmer(reliability corrected ~ 0 + intention + a + b + (1|Study), data = df_x).

summary(modelZ)
modelsummary(modelZ, statistic="p.value")
```

I receive (part of) the following output via:

```
summary(modelZ)
```

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `Y` ~ 0 + intention + a + b + c + (1 | Study)
   Data: df_x

REML criterion at convergence: 14.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.51502 -0.22449 -0.06608  0.36910  1.52729 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Study    (Intercept) 0.22052  0.4696  
 Residual             0.01198  0.1094  
Number of obs: 25, groups:  Study, 15

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)
intention          -0.10750    0.05989  9.27089  -1.795    0.105
a                   0.02907    0.22882 11.72994   0.127    0.901
b                   0.12935    0.26092 11.69105   0.496    0.629
c                  -0.17325    0.22935 12.19998  -0.755    0.464
```

However, if I extract model summary via either the package `modelsummary` or `sjPlot` (same output with both packages), I receive the following output:

```
modelsummary(modelZ, statistic="p.value")
```

| Variable | Estimate | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intention | -0.107 | 0.089 |
| a | 0.029 | 0.900 |
| b | 0.129 | 0.626 |
| c | -0.173 | 0.459 |

As you can see, while the estimates are more or less the same, p-values are quite different, some even on the threshold of non-significant to significant. Does anyone has an idea what could be the underlying mechanisms that caused this? Shouldn't it extract and use the modelx output of lmer?

Thanks in advance!

I searched on forums like Stackoverflow and the CRAN packages for any underlying causes, but didn't find it.

Comment: Is there any chance we can have a [mcve] ... ?? Otherwise this will be hard ...

Comment: Hi Ben, i made some edits to the question - hope this helps gaining more insights into the issue. Could it perhaps be a Z vs T-value issue?

Comment: OK, that helps a little bit.  I wouldn't call these p-values "quite different"!

Comment: Yess true the differences are not that large i used a different example for my edit, but i have some cases for other models in my datasets and subsets that, dependent upon the summary package, are significant or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a reproducible example, my best guess is that this comes from the method used for finite-size correction. `modelsummary()` calls `parameters::model_parameters()` to extract parameters; the `ci_method` options for mixed models are "wald" (no finite-size correction), "satterthwaite", or "kenward".  I believe the `ci_method=` argument will get passed through from `modelsummary()` to `model_parameters()`: you could try `ci_method = "satterthwaite"` and see what happens ...

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(parameters)
library(lmerTest)
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(f = factor(rep(1:8, each = 10)), x  = rnorm(80))
dd$y <- simulate(~ x + (1|f), newdata = dd,
   family = gaussian,
   newparams = list(beta = c(0, 0.5), theta = 1, sigma = 0.5),
   seed = 101)[[1]]
m1 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|f), data = dd)
```

In this example the p-value returned for "satterthwaite" and "kenward" happens to be the same up to three significant digits (for the intercept; we can't see what happens for the slope term.  Could tweak the example, e.g. make the second element of `beta` smaller ...)

```r
model_parameters(m1, effects = "fixed")
# Fixed Effects

Parameter   | Coefficient |   SE |        95% CI | t(76) |      p
-----------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept) |        0.05 | 0.09 | [-0.12, 0.23] |  0.61 | 0.541 
x           |        0.45 | 0.06 | [ 0.33, 0.58] |  7.36 | < .001

Uncertainty intervals (equal-tailed) and p-values (two-tailed) computed
  using a Wald t-distribution approximation.

##
model_parameters(m1, effects = "fixed", ci_method = "satterthwaite")
# Fixed Effects

Parameter   | Coefficient |   SE |        95% CI |    t |    df |      p
------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept) |        0.05 | 0.09 | [-0.16, 0.26] | 0.61 |  7.05 | 0.559 
x           |        0.45 | 0.06 | [ 0.33, 0.58] | 7.36 | 74.05 | < .001

Uncertainty intervals (equal-tailed) and p-values (two-tailed) computed
  using a Wald t-distribution with Satterthwaite approximation.

##

model_parameters(m1, effects = "fixed", ci_method = "kenward")
# Fixed Effects

Parameter   | Coefficient |   SE |        95% CI |    t |    df |      p
------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept) |        0.05 | 0.09 | [-0.16, 0.26] | 0.61 |  7.02 | 0.559 
x           |        0.45 | 0.06 | [ 0.33, 0.58] | 7.31 | 74.04 | < .001

Uncertainty intervals (equal-tailed) and p-values (two-tailed) computed
  using a Wald t-distribution with Kenward-Roger approximation.
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the quick follow up - by adding ci_method = '"satterthwaite"' i get corresponding p-values. Thanks for that! I will mark this question as solved, thank you.